# Resetting css transitions in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-transitions, internet-explorer-10

In trying out CSS transitions I created a little scrolling demo that transitions the `right` css style from some negative number to 0 then restarts when the `transitionend` event fires to get an infinitely scrolling effect.  Here's a Fiddle with my demo - http://jsfiddle.net/XhFdv/

This works in latest FF, Chrome, Safari (win), and Opera.  In IE 10 (tested on both Win 7 and Win 8) the event fires, but trying to set the right property back to the negative number it starts at doesn't appear to be working - it often remains 0 after being set (but not always).

To make things more entertaining, adding `console.log()` or `alert()` is often enough to get it to run as expected.  This is making me think there's something unfinished in the UI layer.  I attempted to wrap more of the style settings in a `setTimeout(..., 0)` so rendering could catch up, but that didn't appear to help.

Is this a bug in IE 10, or is there something I'm missing in the demo script?

Comment: I've seen these kinds of bugs before and they're definitely a pain.  Usually a timeout works but I guess not in this case. I'll have time to fiddle tomorrow so I'll get back to you on this; very peculiar!

Comment: i've increased setTimeout delay up to 10-20 ms and it just works for me.

Comment: I filed a bug with Microsoft a few months ago.  I believe they were able to reproduce the issue and have it as a candidate bug to fix in one of the next major releases.  I didn't make into IE 11, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` works because it blocks script execution. As a secondary measure: something that triggers a repaint or reflow would be the next best thing:

- Toggle `visibility:hidden/visible` via a class attribute change
- Toggle `visibility:hidden/visible` via a style attribute change
- Adding a stylesheet via the CSSOM
- Hiding an element via `display:none`
- Calculating `offsetWidth` or `offsetHeight`
- Triggering a `scroll` event
- Triggering a `:hover` pseudo-class on the sibling of the element in question

**References**

- [Onload in Onload](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2014/09/12/onload-in-onload/)
- [Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)
- [JavaScript Performance Best Practices:Minimize the number of reflows and repaints](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/JavaScript_Performance_Best_Practices#Minimize_the_number_of_reflows_and_repaints)
- [Reflows & Repaints: CSS Performance making your JavaScript slow?](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/)
- [Make the Web Faster: Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow)
- [Reflow Timer Bookmarklet](http://www.browserscope.org/reflow/about)
- [Reflow Selector Test Page](http://stevesouders.com/efws/css-selectors/universal.php)